# How to include only specific module in webpack without transpiling its dependencies?

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, monorepo

I'm working with a monorepo node.js project with the following structure:

```
rootDir
  packageA
  packageB
  packageC
```

I want to produce a bundle of `packageB` code using webpack and babel.js. `packageA` has a lot of exports however only one export is used by `packageA`, let's call the export `utils`.

When I run webpack it recognizes that `packageB` depends on `packageA` so webpack dependecnies graph now includes **all** modules exported by `packageA` in its `index.js` although only one is really needed. So all of the modules in `packageA` are being transpiled by babel.js which even includes the `node_modules` of packages included by files in `packageA`. I've run into numerous issues with transpiling `node_modules` with babel.js. They range from babel.js not being able to deal with non-Javascript files for which loaders [do not exist](https://github.com/data-uri/mimer/issues/3), webpack [not finding](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/1254) certain modules, having mixed esm and commonjs syntax inside some files and many others*.

Other issues could only be solved by commenting out 2 problematic modules exported by `packageA`.

As you can see the solution is not ideal and perhaps not sustainable for long. Is there a way to have webpack transpile `packageA` without transpiling its `node_modules`? I couldn't achieve this despite my numerous regex attempts. Below are my config files:

*I managed to solve the issue by adding `modules: "commonjs"` in babel config however this will disable webpack tree shaking mechanism which means that I need to use a separate `babelrc` for my project.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^(hiredis|transifex)$/)
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /node_modules\/datauri\/index\.js$/,
        loaders: ['shebang-loader', 'babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /node_modules\/needle\/lib\/needle\.js$/,
        loaders: ['file-loader', 'babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            rootMode: 'upward'
          }
        },
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        "/path/to/packageA",
        "/path/to/packageC",
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
      {
        legacy: true
      }
    ],
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator',
      {
        proposal: 'minimal'
      }
    ],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind'
  ],
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current'
        },
        corejs: 3,
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        modules: "commonjs"
      }
    ],
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ],
  env: {
    debug: {
      sourceMaps: 'inline',
      retainLines: true
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that I'm not ignoring `node_modules` in babel.config.js so I added:

```
ignore: [
    /node_modules/
  ]
```

to my babel.config.js. This allowed me to stop using `modules: 'commonjs'` so I guess this did have some effect but I still get errors when trying to run the bundle, errors that resulted from transpiling `node_modules` for example this [error](https://github.com/data-uri/mimer/issues/3).